# how create a custom url in wordpress for page with slash like /se/pagename

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I added a page in wordpress. Wordpress created a url like 
https://mywebsite.com/page-title

but I want to change this url like https://mywebsite.com/se/page-title

My Permalink Settings shows https://mywebsite.com/sample-post/ 
and website is already indexed on google so I can't change my paramlink setting.

I also tried with htaccess and also from wordpress add_rewrite_rule() but no result is coming.

Any help how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to make your page url like `www.example.com/se/se1` instead of `www.example.com/se1` is to create page `se` and `se1` make as child page of `se`.

With this option you'll saved your wordpress website permalink structure, you'll in not need to change your other pages redirects for google indexing